# Does the operation of the CAN peripheral in STM32 wait for the execution of the ISR routine code?

Tags: embedded, interrupt, stm32, can-bus

I'm developing a stack layer on microcontroller STM32L433 that uses the CAN protocol; a fundamental part of the stack is the authentication of the devices.

During authentication it can occur that two (or more) devices start to send a CAN message (authentication message) with the same identifier and different payload (true random value). In this case every device should be able to detect if this message was sent first from another device.

I have studied this case and three situations can occur:

1. the devices start to send message at the same time; in this case only one device is able to sent the message because all others devices detect one error and then abort the transmission.
2. only one device is able to send the message and occupy the bus before all others devices load the transmission MAILBOX of the CAN peripheral, or before the CAN peripheral of the others devices set the message that is going to be sent in the SCHEDULED state.
   In this case, the devices that have not been able to send the message will receive the reception interrupt; within the ISR routine of reception I'm able to abort the transmission.
3. only one device are able to send the message and occupy the bus and all others CAN peripherals of others devices have message in SCHEDULED state and are waiting that bus become idle.
   In this case the devices that have not been able to send the message will receive the reception interrupt. Also in this situation I thought to stop the transmission within the ISR routine of reception (like situation 2) ), but I'm not sure that this is guaranteed for all messages because if the CAN peripheral sets the message that is going to be sent in the TRANSMIT state before the code inside ISR is executed, the operation of abort will have no effect.

My question is (related to the situation 3): Is the message in the transmission MAILBOX in the SCHEDULED state set in the TRANSMISSION state after that the code in the receiving ISR routine is executed or is this thing not guaranteed?

Comment: 1. No that cannot happen since busy bus is not an error. Nodes with more recessive bits in their payload will withdraw and try to send again when the bus becomes available next. This will be handled by the CAN controller and the tx buffer will remain busy/occupied until the message is successfully sent.

Comment: Also I'm not familiar with this particular CAN controller, but generally mailbox registers are just a programmer interface on top of separate rx and tx buffers. That is, once you have written data to a buffer, it will typically get shifted into an actual tx buffer that isn't memory-mapped and you can't access directly.

Comment: @Lundin Many thanks. If error occurs ok, I'm able to abort transmission but my question is related to the situation 3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer on your third case first, no it is not guaranteed that your message is not on the bus, while receiving. Because interrupts might have some latency too, and within this time, the mailbox might be able to go ahead with transmission.

Your "authentication" also sounds a bit troublesome, since nobody from outside could also actually decide which ECU was actually the one that won the arbitration and actually sent that specific message.

We have ECUs in vehicles which decide at runtime, according to certain methods, where they are mounted by pin and some CAN reception, but only in listen mode. TX is actually disabled in the stack. After that, detection has completed, we switch configurations and restart the communications stack and further initialize the software going up.

But these "setups" are usually defined beforehand, e.g. due to master/slave (vehicle/private bus communication), or maybe some connector pins connected to GND / OPEN / U<sub>BAT</sub>, or maybe some bus message which tells on which bus it is on.

That seems to be more reliable than your method.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Regarding your authentication suggestions: in our system we can not define a priori master or slave devices.

Comment: The definition of a master/slave system is a priori, as the system definition contains: a) which ECUs are in the system, b) where each ECU is mounted in the vehicle. If this is determined a priori by e.g, SW compiler switches, you have separate partnumbers usually, but with one partnumber, the SW has to detect the setup / the ECUs mounting "position" by some means. When the ECUs are assembled in the vehicle, you expect the ECU answering on a 700h DiagRequest message with a 708h DIagResponse at exactly the position defined in the setup, and not randomly detected by who wins first arbitration.